# Sorting db info for MVC model

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, dapper

**FindByCounty()**
This function should go out to the db and pull the information. Store the information in their respective classes (which it does)...but then what?

```
public EditCountyViewModel FindByCounty(string countyName)
        {
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@CountyName", value: countyName);

            var query = @"SELECT counties.id
                            , counties.CountyName
                            , counties.Website
                            , counties.Address
                            , counties.City
                            , counties.State
                            , counties.PhonePrimary
                            , counties.PhoneAlt
                            , counties.RecordsOnline
                            , counties.BackToYear
                            , counties.Cost
                            , products.ProductName
                            , products.Description
                            , countyproduct.TurnTime_MinHours
                            , countyproduct.TurnTime_MaxHours
                            , countyproduct.Price
                        FROM
                            counties, countyproduct, products
                        WHERE
                            counties.CountyName = @CountyName AND countyproduct.countiesID = counties.ID AND countyproduct.productsID = products.ID;";

            EditCountyViewModel editCountyVM = new EditCountyViewModel();
        EditProductsViewModel editProductVM = new EditProductsViewModel();
        editProductVM.ProductList = this.db.Query<Product>(query, new { countyName }).ToList();
        editCountyVM.county = this.db.Query<County>(query, new { countyName }).FirstOrDefault();


        return editCountyVM;
        }
```

**Details() on HOMEcontroller**
I am thinking i should just query all the information and then use LINQ in this function to piece out the information i need.

```
public ActionResult Details(string countyName)
    {
        var model = repository.FindByCounty(countyName);
        return View(model);
    }
```

As my code stands, It does not run because in the `FindByCounty()` it is returning only one of the needed elements `editCountyVM`. Now i could change the output of the function and return the other `editProductVM` but then i wouldn't have the first set of info (editCountyVM).

I believe the problem is the method i am going about obtaining this information. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like if you want to return both `editCountyVM` and `editProductVM` you could change the return type of your method to a `Tuple<EditCountyViewModel,EditProductsViewModel>`. Then make your return statement as follows:

```
return new Tuple<EditCountyViewModel,EditProductsViewModel>(editCountyVM, editProductVM);
```

Comment: that does makes sense but it doesn't quite answer my initial problem. In the `FindByCounty()` i can only return one item. In the code above i have it returning `editCountyVM`...however, i want to have both of these (`editCountyVM` & `editProductVM`) returned so i use them as my model in the home controller.

Comment: Oh I see. You want to return both ViewModels?

Comment: essentially yes. However, i feel that there is probably a better way to do it than how i am trying to. Like i said in the OP. I feel that i could do some of the sorting using LINQ inside the home controller. But since i'm new-ish to MVC i can't quite overcome this right now

Comment: I agree you have some other design considerations here but I believe my updated answer will solve your immediate problem.

Comment: This is why i love this site. I just learned something new #Tuples<>